# How to implement Python's MLPClassifier with gridsearchCV?

Tags: python, neural-network, scikit-learn, cross-validation, hyperparameter

I am trying to implement Python's ***MLPClassifier*** with ***10 fold*** cross-validation using ***gridsearchCV*** function. Here is a chunk of my code:

```
parameters={
'learning_rate': ["constant", "invscaling", "adaptive"],
'hidden_layer_sizes': [(100,1), (100,2), (100,3)],
'alpha': [10.0 ** -np.arange(1, 7)],
'activation': ["logistic", "relu", "Tanh"]
}

clf
= gridSearchCV(estimator=MLPClassifier,param_grid=parameters,n_jobs=-1,verbose=2,cv=10)
```

Though,I am not sure if `hidden_layer_sizes: [(100,1), (100,2), (100,3)]` is correct. Here, I am trying to tune ***'hidden layer size'*** & ***'number of neurons'***. I would like to give this ***'tuple'*** parameter for ***hidden_layer_sizez: 1, 2, 3***, and **neurons: 10, 20, 30,...,100**.

But
I do not know if it is the correct way to do it. Therefore, I am choosing default neurons to be ***100*** in each layer.

Can
anyone advise please?

Comment: I am very new to Python and was going through this post. My query is similar and response on setting up of Hidden layers helped a lot. However, I am **unable to set up alpha** in same way as mentioned above. Any help on this? I mean when I am setting up alpha as *alpha': [10.0 ** -np.arange(1, 7)]*, it is giving me error.

Comment: the alpha parameter of the MLPClassifier is a scalar. [10.0 ** -np.arange(1, 7)], is a vector. Which works because it is passed to gridSearchCV which then passes each element of the vector to a new classifier. Have you set it up in the same way?

Comment: `'hidden_layer_sizes': [x for x in product(range(1,100), range(1,3))]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A tuple of the form $(i_1, i_2, i_3, ... , i_n)$ gives you a network with $n$ hidden layers, where $i_k$ gives you the number of neurons in the $k$th hidden layer.

If you want three hidden layers with $10,30$ and $20$ neurons, your tuple would need to look like $(10,30,20)$.

$(100,1)$ would mean that the second hidden layer only has one neuron.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I still do not get it. I would like to tune two things simultaneously; 'Number of layers ranging from 1 to 3', and 'Number of neurons in each layer ranging as 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 100'. Can you please show in my above example code how to do it? Alternately, let's say I fix on 3 hidden layers. Now,  I want to tune only neurons ranging as 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 100

Comment: you need to spell out all the combinations [(10,),...(100,),...(100,100,100)]. you can use [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) to generate them, e.g. `[x for x in itertools.product((10,20,30,40,50,100),repeat=3)]` if you really want all the combinations of of neurons for 3 hidden layers...

Comment: Thanks! I get it now what you mean, however, can you please provide a working example in my above code?

Comment: `'hidden_layer_sizes': [x for x in itertools.product((10,20,30,40,50,100),repeat=3)]` ?

Answer (score 4):

You can implement MLPClassifier with GridSearchCV in scikit-learn as follows (other parameters are also available):

```
GRID = [
    {'scaler': [StandardScaler()],
     'estimator': [MLPClassifier(random_state=RANDOM_SEED)],
     'estimator__solver': ['adam'],
     'estimator__learning_rate_init': [0.0001],
     'estimator__max_iter': [300],
     'estimator__hidden_layer_sizes': [(500, 400, 300, 200, 100), (400, 400, 400, 400, 400), (300, 300, 300, 300, 300), (200, 200, 200, 200, 200)],
     'estimator__activation': ['logistic', 'tanh', 'relu'],
     'estimator__alpha': [0.0001, 0.001, 0.005],
     'estimator__early_stopping': [True, False]
     }
]

PIPELINE = Pipeline([('scaler', None), ('estimator', MLPClassifier())])
```

You can then run GridSearch as the following:

```
grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator=PIPELINE, param_grid=GRID, 
                            scoring=make_scorer(accuracy_score),# average='macro'), 
                            n_jobs=-1, cv=split, refit=True, verbose=1, 
                            return_train_score=False)

grid_search.fit(X, y)
```